# Kubectl Unable to describe on HPA

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

When I'm trying to describe on hpa following error is thrown:

```
kubectl describe hpa go-auth
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

My kubectl version is :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.7-gke.7", GitCommit:"b80664a77d3bce5b4701bc881d972b1a702290bf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-04T03:12:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading to 1.12. It looks like GKE bug.

Comment: Beware of [`kubectl` version skew](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/#kubectl).  Running `kubectl` **v1.14** with `kubeapi-server` **v1.12** is not supported. As per [`kubectl` docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/#kubectl): *You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.2 client should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 master. Using the latest version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues*. Give it another try using `kubectl` **v1.12.x**.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello, great comment. Can you please post it as a answer for future? There is nothing to reply more in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of [`kubectl` version skew](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/#kubectl). Running `kubectl` **v1.14** with `kube-apiserver` **v1.12** is not supported.

As per [`kubectl` docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin):

> You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version
>   difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.2 client should work
>   with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 master. Using the latest version of kubectl
>   helps avoid unforeseen issues.

Give it another try using `kubectl` **v1.12.x** and you probably will get rid of this problem. Also, take a look at the [#568](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/568) issue (especially [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/568#issuecomment-447924702) comment), which addresses the same problem that you have.

If you are wondering on how to manage multiple `kubectl` versions, I recommend this read: [Using different kubectl versions with multiple Kubernetes clusters](https://medium.com/@eduardobaitello/using-different-kubectl-versions-with-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-a3ad8707b87b).